# how to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery(sql, params) without parameters and waiting for a data result

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When i call a sp using EF with return data i use

```
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<return Datatype>("name", parameter)
```

but, when i want to execute a stored procedure with no parameters and receive data, how to do that... i try

```
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<return Datatype>("name", null)
```

but gives me a error: "The value cant be null".

so, my question is, how to execute a sp if there are results returned ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<Datatype>("name");
```

The second parameter has the `params` keyword. Which means you can have from zero to `n` parameters. Read more on [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

Comment: ok ... I thought they were mandatory parameter of the function SqlQuery. Thanks and regards.

Comment: I thought it was mandatory also, because Intellisense shows two overloads, each taking 2 and 3 params respectively! So i passed an empty object array, For Example, this works... dbCtx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sql, new object[] { });